# How do I generate a message in a User Edit View using Django

Tags: python, django, message

I am trying to generate a message when someone edits their user profile.  The code that I have created is below.  The profile gets updated and returns me to my home page, but doesn't generate a message.

Please help.  Thanks.

base.html

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    {{ message }}<br/>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages

class UserEditView(generic.UpdateView):
form_class = EditProfileForm
template_name = 'registration/edit_profile.html'    
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user

def get_success_message(self):      
    msg = 'Profile has been updated!'       
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
messages.success(self.request, f'Profile Updated!')
```

Instead of:

```
msg = 'Profile has been updated!'       
messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, msg)
```

Comment: Just changed the code, but the same thing happened.  I get redirected to my home page with no indication that the update worked.

Comment: Its almost like using messages with 'reverse_lazy' causes no message to be generated.

Comment: Please see comments above, and let me know if anyone has any more suggestions.